# Blender 3.0 geometry nodes random per object material

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

In Blender 3.0's geometry nodes I would assign a random per object material like the first picture. But the result is like the second. The nodes in the pictures are only one of many tests that i did but i can't obtain the desire result. I apologize for my ignorance, I don't know a lot of all node functions, especially with this amazing new version that I am still learning to use.

[image: Expectation]

[image: Reality]

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the objects after instantiation and assign different materials to the two resulting groups:

[image]